# C function explain

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

float orizousa(int n[]);

int main() {
    int a[12];
    int i;
    printf("grapse tous sintelestes kai to apotelesma tis prwtis eksiswsis \n (me seira:1os-2os-3os sintelestis - apotelesma) :");

    for(i=0; i<=11; i++) {
        scanf(" %d",&a[i]);
    }

    float g = orizousa(a);
    printf(" %f",g);

    return 0;
}

float orizousa(int a[]) {
    float d,dx1,dx2,dx3,x1,x2,x3;

    d = a[0]*a[4]*a[8] + a[1]*a[5]*a[6] + a[2]*a[3]*a[7] - a[2]*a[4]*a[7] - a[1]*a[3]*a[8] - a[0]*a[5]*a[7] ;
    dx1 = a[9]*a[4]*a[8] + a[1]*a[5]*a[11] + a[2]*a[10]*a[7] - a[2]*a[4]*a[7] - a[1]*a[10]*a[8] - a[9]*a[5]*a[7] ;
    dx2 = a[0]*a[10]*a[8] + a[0]*a[5]*a[6] + a[2]*a[3]*a[11] - a[2]*a[10]*a[11] - a[1]*a[3]*a[8] - a[0]*a[5]*a[11] ;
    dx3 = a[0]*a[4]*a[11] + a[1]*a[10]*a[6] + a[9]*a[3]*a[7] - a[9]*a[4]*a[7] - a[1]*a[3]*a[11] - a[0]*a[10]*a[7] ;

    return d;
}
```

In this code, in the line that says

```
float g = orizousa(a);
```

why do we put only `a` in, and not `a[]` for example??

How can I return 2 values, for example `d` and `dx`, from one function??

Comment: Read my answer. It explains what happens behind the scenes in C. Should clarify your doubts a lot

Comment: You can return a struct, or modify input parameter if passed by address, but use it careuflly because it involve pointer.

Answer (score 1):

when it comes to array just the name, passes the array's address and the function accepting it will be pointing to the same memory address. it more like reference variable in C++.

u cant return more than one value at a time. if the data is of similar type u can copy to an array and pass the array back

Answer (score 1):

> float g=orizousa(a);
>
> int a[]

a is an array of integer type where the variable name 'a' denotes the reference of array a.

function orizousa takes a reference parameter of integer type. thats why you have to pass a instead of a[]

if you want to return d and dx then simply add another reference to your function.

```
orizousa(int a[],float pReturn[])
{
  ....
  pReturn[0]=d;
  pReturn[1]=dx;

}
```

Comment: i just show him the way. did not write full code. again if you want to return two value of float type How can I return 2 values, for example d and dx, from one function??

Comment: i got your point. local reference will be out of scope when return. i have changed my approach.

Answer (score 1):

**why we put only 'a' in, and not a[] for example??**

When passing array as arguments to functions in C, we have to pass the variable name only, unless you want to pass only one element of the array, which in that case would be float g = orizousa(a[2]) for example. But the function orizousa receives an array, so you have to pass the entire array.

**and how can i return 2 values??**

There is no way to return 2 values in C from a function. But what you can do is pass variables as reference. You can do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float orizousa(int n[]);

int main()
{
     int a[12];
     int i;
     printf("grapse tous sintelestes kai to apotelesma tis prwtis eksiswsis \n (me seira:1os-2os-3os sintelestis - apotelesma) :");`enter code here`

     for(i=0;i<=11;i++)
     { scanf(" %d",&a[i]);}

     float d, dx1, dx2, dx3;

     float g=orizousa(a, &d, &dx1, &dx2, &dx3);
     printf(" %f",g);

     return 0;
}

float orizousa(int a[], float *d, float *dx1, float *dx2, float *dx3)
{

    *d=a[0]*a[4]*a[8] + a[1]*a[5]*a[6] + a[2]*a[3]*a[7] - a[2]*a[4]*a[7] - a[1]*a[3]*a[8] - a[0]*a[5]*a[7] ;
    *dx1=a[9]*a[4]*a[8] + a[1]*a[5]*a[11] + a[2]*a[10]*a[7] - a[2]*a[4]*a[7] - a[1]*a[10]*a[8] - a[9]*a[5]*a[7] ;
    *dx2=a[0]*a[10]*a[8] + a[0]*a[5]*a[6] + a[2]*a[3]*a[11] - a[2]*a[10]*a[11] - a[1]*a[3]*a[8] - a[0]*a[5]*a[11] ;
    *dx3=a[0]*a[4]*a[11] + a[1]*a[10]*a[6] + a[9]*a[3]*a[7] - a[9]*a[4]*a[7] - a[1]*a[3]*a[11] - a[0]*a[10]*a[7] ;
}
```

Comment: why you are using two reference variable for 2 value? you can simply pass a reference of 2 sized array

Comment: @qwr Yes, i edited now
user3200809 wouldn't that be more confusing and pointless?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and pointers are intimately related. When you write "g=orizousa(a)" you are passing the function a copy of the address of the first element of the array a.

To return two values from a function you can either pass the address of the two variables you want to change or put them into a structure and return the structure.

```
void foo( int* x, int* y ) { 
  *x = 1; *y = 2; 
}
```

called as

```
int xx = 0;
int yy = 0;
foo(&xx,&yy);
```

or as a struct

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} args;
```

either pass in as argument

```
void foo(args* arg) { 
  args.x=1; 
  args.y=2; 
}
```

called as

```
args arg;
foo(&arg);
```

or returned

```
args foo() { 
  args arg = { 1,2 }; 
  return arg; 
}
```

called as

```
args arg = foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing an array to the function `orizousa`, you are passing the address of the array, not an actual copy (atleast in this case). In C, `a` actually stores the address of the first element of the array. So, you are passing the address of the first element of the array. `*a` will print the value of the first element. we cannot pass `a[]` because that is a syntax error.

To return 2 values, you can declare a variable in the main function and pass it as a reference variable to `orizousa`. Then you can return `d` and store the value of dx1 in the reference variable.